# Event.target returns undefined in React type button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have a React form that has one **submit** button of `type='submit'` and another one which is a **delete** button of `type='button'`. My problem is I couldn't get the `event.target` that I want in the onClick function of the delete button.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.target.testing.value    // This will work
}

handleDelete = (event) => {     
  event.target.testing.value    // This doesn't work, returns undefined
}

render(){
  return(
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <input id='testing' value='anything' />

       <button type='submit'/>
       <button type='button' onClick={this.handleDelete} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

I understand that in the `handleDelete` function, the event param is the event of the button so if I do `event.target.value` it will give me the value of the button if the button has the value property.

Is there a way so that I can access the value of the `input` in the `handleDelete` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before moving forward, you should read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Then, fix your code (assuming you're using [class fields](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), if not, follow the example in the link above)...

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  handleClear = (event) => { 
    // assuming you want to clear the input     
    // you won't need the event if you utilize state
    this.setState({ value: "" });
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target; // same as "value = event.target.value"

    this.setState({ value });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the page from freshing when "submit" is clicked
    alert(this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="testInput">Input: </label>
        <input id="testInput" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClear}>Clear</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was trying to do it in such as way that state is not required. However, this is the way that works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are brother elements, button cannot get his siblings by event.target.
If you want to change the value. I recommand bind state to your input value, and then if you want to delete, setState input value to ''.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to bind the reference to `this` to the event handler

You need to either do the binding in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Or you could also do the binding like this:

`<button type='button' onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this} />`

Read this, it´s very clear and well written as this is a common question: 
[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)